# formula for conditional formatting in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, formula

Google sheets seating chart

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to automatically highlight the agents name based off their role. There is a chart to the side of the seating chart layout that has the name and role in column c and d. The seating chart is in G:N so I need it to look at the name in the seating chart area and find it in the list to the left and based off the role next to it, highlight the agents cell.

Any help on the right formula/function to use would be great. I've tried just about every nested IF or vlook up I can think of. I can't share the actual sheet since its for work, but here is an example of what it looks like. It should be open access, if not please let me know.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LVLS69csWIrL3w3eRxQj2XpLwLS4VGaLGn48a4X8KqE/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these two custom formulas in F1 of conditional formatting:

```
=(VLOOKUP(F1,$C$3:$D$11,2,false)="phone")

=(VLOOKUP(F1,$C$3:$D$11,2,false)="email")
```

Apply both to range F1:L

Comment: This worked perfectly. Had to tweak slightly to fit the actual sheet, but yes, thank you!